# zend - Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, zend-framework, backend

In `indexcontroller.php` code

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $table;

    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->table=$table;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $users=$this->table->fetchall();

        foreach($users as $user){


            echo $user->getName().'<br/>';

        }

        exit;

        return new ViewModel();
    }

}
```

this is my module.php file code

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{

    const VERSION = '3.0.3-dev';

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
        'factories'=>[
        Model\UserTable::class=>function($container){
            $tableGateway=$container->get(Model\UserTableGateway::class);
            return new MOdel\UserTable($tableGateway);
        },
        Model\UserTableGateway::class=>function($container){
            $adapter=$container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
            $resultSetPrototype=new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\User);
            return new TableGateway('user', $adapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
        }
        ]
        ];


}
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return[
    'factories'=>[
    Controller\IndexConroller::class=>function($container){
        return new Controller\IndexController(
        $container->get(Model\UserTable::class)
        );
    }
    ]
    ];

}
}
```

When run this code it shows an error like this:

File:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ZEND\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\module\Application\src\Controller\IndexController.php:17
```

Message:

> Too few arguments to function
>   Application\Controller\IndexController::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ZEND\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\Factory\InvokableFactory.php
>   on line 30 and exactly 1 expected

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Improved formatting and text

Comment: Fix Controller\IndexConroller::class on Controller\IndexController::class. [class Module => function getControllerConfig()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module.php file, the MOdel shoulb be Model.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
        'factories'=>[
        Model\UserTable::class=>function($container){
            $tableGateway=$container->get(Model\UserTableGateway::class);
            **return new MOdel\UserTable($tableGateway);**
        },
        Model\UserTableGateway::class=>function($container){
            $adapter=$container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
            $resultSetPrototype=new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\User);
            return new TableGateway('user', $adapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
        }
        ]
        ];
}
```

Comment: i have changed , but same problem again

Comment: return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
 'App',
]; here i need to make any changes or no need???